# Is there such a thing as third party SQL Server word breaker for Hungarian language?

Tags: sql-server, localization, full-text-search, wordbreaker

I want to use `CONTAINS` on a fulltext index and use `FORMSOF(...)` on Hungarian data.
Is it possible? I KNOW it is not supported by default in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server can load custom word breakers and stemmers, see [Word Breakers and Stemmers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142509.aspx). If you cannot find a Hungarian stemmer there is always the possibility of creating one your own: [Word Breaker and Stemmer Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms693176%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), see also [Getting the LRSAMPLE custom word-breaker to work on 64-bit SQL Server 2008](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlfts/archive/2010/12/11/getting-the-lrsample-custom-word-breaker-to-work-on-64-bit-sql-server-2008.aspx). You don't have to implement the dictionary yourself, you could simply reuse for instance the [libstemmer Hungarian Snowball algorithm](http://snowball.tartarus.org/algorithms/hungarian/stemmer.html) and package it as a SQL Server stemmer.

Comment: That's way more work than what I can do on this project. I was hoping for a nice link to "Download Hungarian word breaker here"... :( No wonder I didn't find any googling by myself.