# Choose an appropriate language for full text index in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, full-text-indexing

I want to add a column with Hungarian language to my table, and I want to full-text-index it.

The problem is that SQL Server doesn't have Hungarian language registered, and I can't find any good tip by Microsoft about what's the best language to choose from.

Here are [the languages that are supproted](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176076.aspx)

And this is [the best tip I found](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142507.aspx#breaking).

The text is specific about western languages, but Hungarian is not western.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the closest widely known language to Hungarian is Finnish [(see here)](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_closest_language_to_Hungarian).  Unfortunately, SQL Server FTS does not seem to support Finnish either [(see here)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176076.aspx).

You always have the option to create your own word breaker and word stemmer and load it into SQL Server FTS.   For more information on how to do that for Hungarian, see this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123546/is-there-such-a-thing-as-third-party-sql-server-word-breaker-for-hungarian-langu).  Of course, doing something like this would be a signficant undertaking, but I think there may not be any better options out there.